# Unable to edit the "customize" section and the "widget" section is populating unknown code

Tags: customization, widgets, 500-internal-error, content-width

My WordPress site is experiencing some major issues. I am getting a 500 server error when attempting to change the "customize" side bar, and the "widget" section is acting really weird (populating many weird unknown codes :/

[image]